# * not expanded in subprocess.Popen (security implications)

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, code-injection

this works but shell injection is a security risk

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['mv ./*.pdf ./target.pdf'], shell=True)
```

this doesn't work as * won't glob

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['mv', './*.pdf', './target.pdf'])
```

I'm watching a directory. How can I rename an arriving pdf to target.pdf without compromising security?

Comment: Why not use `glob` inside your python script first to find the filenames.

Comment: Why use `subprocess` for that when you can use `shutil.move()`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm using watchdog to rename any arriving pdf file to target.pdf which is passed into a tika-parser by subprocess.Popen so how would i glob first?

Comment: @nauer I'm a beginner. Thanks for the tip. I will post my clunky solution which I'm sure could be done better...

Comment: @user1613312 same way you are using listdir in the answer you ahve posted. Simply do `sources = glob.glob('*.pdf')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `glob` command from the `glob` module to get shell like path extensions:

> `glob.glob(pathname, *, recursive=False)`
>
> Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname, which must be a string containing a path specification. pathname can be either absolute (like `/usr/src/Python-1.5/Makefile`) or relative (like `../../Tools/*/*.gif`), and can contain shell-style wildcards. Broken symlinks are included in the results (as in the shell).
>
> If `recursive` is true, the pattern `**` will match any files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by an os.sep, only directories and subdirectories match.
>
> (taken from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html))

In your case it could look like this:

```
import shutil
import glob

sources = glob.glob('*.pdf')
destination = "target.pdf"
for file in sources:
    shutil.move(file, destination)
```

Comment: source = glob.glob('*.pdf')
destination = "target.pdf"
for file in source:
    shutil.move(file,destination)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
import os
import shutil

source = os.listdir(os.curdir)
destination = "target.pdf"
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".pdf"):
        shutil.move(files,destination)
```